# How do I Update layouts for long and notlong resource qualifiers?

Tags: android, layout, resources

I noticed that although my drawable resources are being scaled down properly by android, the bottom of the layouts are getting chopped off on smaller screens(I assume notlong screens, as my testing device is a Droid which I believe is long, right?)

Should I be updating the layout files and putting them in a res/layout-notlong folder or something like that?  Or should Android be handling this differently?

Answer (score 2):

You rarely need to use -long and -notlong.  You should be designing your layouts with layout managers that resize themselves to adjust to the screen size.

Comment: She's talking about the *Layout classes that Android provides. LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc. Those same tags you're putting in your XML layouts. :)

Comment: My problem seems to be somewhere in this realm.  I am mostly using RelativeLayouts for all of my layouts and everything is specified using dpi (except for text, which uses sp I think).